# How can a government with gods remain stable for at least 500 years?

Tags: magic, government, gods

You and some friends got together, messed around, destroyed the world, became gods, and made a new one, in about that order. **Your goal is to create a government for this new world with the following requirements:**

1. You and your 20 or so friends want to be in unremovable positions of power for the next 500 years at least. If there is a way to remove someone's political power, you only want other gods to be able to.
2. You want to avoid letting one god be able to abuse the citizens of your world, but you also want to have them actually be able to perform government action. (i.e. no one can start instituting jim crow laws and you don't want to be Queens of England)
3. You want it to keep working even if gods die.

Those three things are the important parts, everything below this is for clarity. You can ignore or change parts if you need to.

Making this easier, you have the following things:

1. Disposing of one of you is really hard. You all have incredible power (about that of a Norse god), and can only be killed in incredibly specific ways. i.e. the Seer of Truth can only be killed by a shark tooth on a specific hill at night. Good luck doing that to somebody who can see the future and read minds. This means a rouge god or angry civilians can't really mess things up.
2. You are basically decent people and trust each other to some degree. You've all been through a lot together, and, as everyone now is, they all want what's best for the mortals you will rule. You have differing opinions on what that means, but you all want the best.
3. You are all fairly reasonable. This is probably the most unrealistic thing here, but as you now are, you are willing to make reasonable compromises, as long as it doesn't lock you out of doing things. i.e. the king of time will agree to not retroactively prevent things from happening without consent.

However, you have the following things working against you.

1. People change. Right now, everyone want's the best, but 500 years is a long time, and it might be longer. You want to make sure that the Guardian of Fauna doesn't snap and start murdering litterers. Or, at least, you want to be able to stop him.
2. You only trust each other to *some* degree. There is still some tension between you about how things were done to create the world and in your prior life. Compounding the issue is this:
3. You aren't particularly mature. The oldest of you is 27 and the youngest is 17. Evidence shows that While you may have much more knowledge, you probably won't ever become much more mature.
4. You won't last forever. Offing another god is really hard, but doing it yourself is easy. There's no real telling how long anyone will want to live, or if they'll want to live forever. And there are no ways to replace gods.

**What precautions do you take to meet the three requirements? Also, is there a specific form of government that makes this easier?**

Thanks!

Comment: If there is a problem with clarity, please tell me, and I will fix it ASAP.

Comment: Does the principle 'absolute power corrupts absolutely' applies?

Comment: It looks like you've built your world and are asking about decisions individuals in this world will make.

Comment: seems pretty despotic. Gods from just about any pantheon are fairly vane, greedy and power hungry. Even if they initially agree to set up this government, Id imagine it wont be long before they are scheming to eliminate everyone else. Being that you cant replace a god once they are gone, it may not take 500 years before there is only 1 left

Comment: "You all have incredible power (about that of a Norse god)" - even if ordinary people can't kill gods, can they reliably counter their powers and possibly imprison them?

Comment: @Shpennings, I have not, actually. I mostly want to know if the concept is viable. I pulled the names out of thin air.

Comment: I think people are confused by a choice of words and grammatical constructions and vote to close as 'too story-based'. This is not a question about characters and their actions. This is a question about a form of government. The question can be restated in this form without losing anything: 'What form of government would be stable for over 500 years under conditions X, Y, Z?'

Comment: Thanks Otkin. I will do that.

Comment: You might look at Brandon Sanderson's Warbreaker - the story centers around a kingdom run by gods.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the simplest method to achieve this is to simply:

**Have children.**

"You and your 20 or so friends want to be in unremovable positions of power for the next 500 years at least. If there is a way to remove someone's political power, you only want other gods to be able to." - That's fine, your children will be gods too! And you can raise them as ancient kings raised their heirs, preparing them for rulership of the new world.

"You want to avoid letting one god be able to abuse the citizens of your world, but you also want to have them actually be able to perform government action. (i.e. no one can start instituting jim crow laws and you don't want to be Queens of England)" - No one god would be able to abuse the citizens of this new world - in fact, *none of them*, even with their combined powers, would want to do such a thing. How would they explain to an innocent child that they just discriminated against millions of innocent people all around the world? And since your children will hold you to morals, they also would probably like it if you left your creation to its own course, to see how it played out (the recreation of government is cool).

"You want it to keep working even if gods die." - Well, your children inherit your godly powers, do they not?

P. S. "And there are no ways to replace gods." You're not replacing them with any other individuals, you're just making new gods.

Hope this answer helps!

Comment: "That's fine, your children will be gods too!" That needs to be postulated, it's not a given.

Comment: Innocent babies all over the world have had no trouble at all adapting to the caste systems.  Especially when they are the top caste.

Comment: Huh. Did not think about that. Good ideas.

Comment: Lelu, are you a parent? I see some serious flaws here. Look up the titanomachy.

Answer (score 1):

**The Gauntlets of Kings and Queens**

Create a gauntlet challenge that is easy for the god to pass, but would be impossible for a human to pass without a decent level of technology.  Each god makes their own gauntlet with a prizes at the end.  The gauntlet can be geared to each god's strengths.

None of the prizes would be world-ending super weapons, but cloaks of invisibility and Seven-league boots would give a pretty big advantage to anyone who possessed them.  **They'd also be designed to provide an advantage against your god kin in case things get heated between you.**

If one or two gods start screwing things up again, the other gods can simply run their gauntlets and hand out some pretty powerful items to help.  This also works if a human dispot gains power.  Simply hand out items like this to the people and let them topple the dispot themselves.  Just be sure to collect the prizes afterwards and put them back behind the gauntlet.

Eventually humans will progress to a point they can run the gauntlet themselves with technological and magical help.  At this point, the prizes should provide some advantages, but humans should have progressed enough they'll be able to reverse engineer the treasure.

Gear the gauntlets to involve massive resources to complete, needing large decentralized skill-sets.  This should force humanity to get to a reasonable level of technological and sociological maturity before you turn over the reigns to them.

Answer (score 1):

**The U.S. Senate**
(*) Including Unanimous Consent to Act & Gods’ Filibuster: Every act is legislatively completed by the gods’ Senate passing a law through unanimous consent. This includes succession of power and removal from gods’ office. Reasonable acts can and will be passed by unanimous consent. But every god gets a veto, and vetoes can themselves only be overcome by unanimous consent. This ensures nothing changes until a god gets tired and chooses to vote against himself.

You want power for 500 years? Perfect, the Senate was purposefully engineered to move slowly, and effectively stymie radical changes.

There’s no such thing as gridlock, because inaction is a feature not a bug. Even if all the gods die, and there are no more gods to effect new legislation, things will continue on just the way they are.

The President Pro Temp: Mediates the priority of legislative acts, when there is multiple legislation.
The Seargeant-at-Arms of Senate: gods have imbued this entity with the power to enforce all current laws by removing all reprobates from existence.

Comment: Great idea! Slow-moving and a lot of tedious rules to ensure consensus seems a great way to frustrate many of those immature gods, and eventually some might suicide or lash out. The fewer survivors when the revolution occurs after the frustrated-god-wars, the better.

Comment: Hey! that's pretty good! Unanimous decisions usually halt progress and change completely (see articles of confederation), but otherwise, this has some very good ideas.